# selecting max value from table with two variable colums (microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

i´m working with a table that looks like this:

Start
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uibc3.png

My desired result would look like this:

Result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0sic.png

So i´m triyng to select the max value from two "combined" colums. If the values are the same amount (Part C), the outcome doesn't matter.
I tried to order the table by max value and then using distinct but the result didn't turn out as expected

Could you please offer a solution or some insight to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at row_number() and windowed functions.

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by part order by amount desc, zone) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

For each `part`, this gives you the row with the highest amount; if there are top ties, column `zone` is used to break them.

If you want to allow ties, then use `rank()` instead, like:

```
rank() over(partition by part order by amount desc) rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **SUB Query**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
PART VARCHAR(50),
ZONE VARCHAR(10),
Amt INT)


Insert Into @T Values ('PartA','71H',1),('PartA','75H',2),('PartB','98D',1),('PartB','98A',3),('PartC','75H',1),('PartC','52H',1)

SELECT M.PART,MIN(M.Zone) AS ZONE,S.AMOUNT
FROM @T M
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Part,MAX(Amt) as AMOUNT From @T
GROUP BY PART) S ON S.AMOUNT=M.Amt AND S.PART=M.PART
GROUP BY M.PART,S.AMOUNT
ORDER BY M.PART
```